# What is the best method to upload an image/videos to the server from android application?

Tags: android, performance, image-uploading

I want to upload an image/videos to the server from my android application. I got two references from googling to uploading the files.  The approaches are,

1.Base64 conversion

2.Multipart approach

if i choose base64 method for video uploading, the string length of base64 gets high. Does this create any problem in uploading?

What is the difference between these two approaches. And which one is best for better performance? 
Maybe this question have been asked by many people. But i haven't get exact solution for this.Please help me on this to get clear solution.

Comment: have u searched for it ??

Comment: yes. but i couldn't get a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Multipart approach` is the best approach in this case you only have to give image rest is handled by the libraries.

Comment: Are you sure is this the correct answer for what is asked? According to me its not.